# Understanding navigation in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

Trying to build a simple JSF application. One i don't get is, what mechanism is to use to trigger page reload. I have tried following

```
<h:selectOneMenu 
    id="ChallengesListBox" 
    onchange="submit()" 
    valueChangeListener="#{bean.projectselected}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.projectnames}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

with

```
public String submit() {
    this.description.setRendered(true);
    return null;
}
```

But this has no effect. The bean method

```
public String submit()
```

remains untouched, as I can see in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to navigation. There are many causes why a bean action method is not invoked. You can find them all in this answer: [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

I suspest that you've either simply no `<h:form>`, or that you have multiple buttons in the form (the first one would then be invoked on `submit()`), or that the button is by itself not `rendered` during processing of the form submit.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this JSF 1.x style approach is very clumsy. As you're apparently already on JSF 2.x, I suggest the following much simpler approach:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.projectname}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.projectnames}" />
    <f:ajax render="somepanel" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup id="somepanel">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.description}" rendered="#{not empty bean.projectname}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

*(this will render the `#{bean.description}` value whenever the `#{bean.projectname}` is not null/empty according to the selection of the drop down list)*

And make sure that you remove all `binding` attributes to the backing bean. Also make sure that the bean is `@ViewScoped` whenever you have input/button components inside the `<h:panelGroup id="somepanel">`.